# ASP.net wizard Design

Tags: asp.net, controls

I have requirement to create an asp.net wizard control which will be re usable in a number of projects. I do not wish to use the out of the box ASP.net wizard control as for the number of pages etc for the systems it is too basic. At the moment i am trying to come up with a good re-usable extensible design which will be easily implemented accross multiple systems. Wondering if others have done someting similar to this?? have any gotchas, advice etc for the design? Examples etc??

thanks
Niall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with the asp wizard control and customising to suit needs. Very happy with the results. Easy control to work with and easy to extend and modify all areas by implementing custom itemplate classes